# How to get data frame ready in order to use vegan package?

Tags: r, dplyr, vegan

I have a dataset where I want to count how many unique species are in each plot each year at two different sites. In this dataset, plant composition was taken numerous times throughout the growing season. I essentially want the total number of unique species in each plot each year AND which species make up that total number.

For example, I want this information:

plot - A1
total_species - 3
species - Apan, Acmi, Cest
year - 2016

A subset of the data frame:

```
structure(list(species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Acmi", 
"Acsa", "Amla", "Animal_Disturbance", "Ansp", "Apan", "Arel", 
"Assp", "Bare_Ground", "Bavu", "Brown", "Cahi", "Cape", "Ceor", 
"Cest", "Crsp", "Daca", "Dagl", "Dasp", "Elre", "Erci", "Ersp", 
"Eugr", "Frve", "Hisp", "Hype", "Litter", "Pesp", "Phpr", "Pore", 
"Posp", "Prsp", "Ptaq", "Ruac", "Rusp", "Soca", "Soju", "Sosp", 
"Syla", "Taof", "Thar", "Trsp", "Uhsp", "Unknown", "Vear", "Vert_Litter"
), class = "factor"), site = c("kbs", "kbs", "kbs", "kbs", "kbs", 
"kbs", "kbs", "kbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs"
), plot = c("D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "B4", 
"B4", "B4", "B4", "B4", "B4", "B4", "B4", "B4", "C3", "C3", "C3", 
"C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", 
"C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", 
"C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", 
"C3", "C3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
"D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
"D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
"D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", 
"A4", "A4", "A4", "A4")), row.names = 1022:1122, class = "data.frame")
```

I've tried:

```
comp1 <- comp %>% 
        group_by(site, plot, year, species) %>% 
        summarise(species_total = count(species))
```

I eventually need this data to be transposed into wide format in order to work in the vegan package in R to calculate various diversity indices.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `count` as

```
library(dplyr)
count(comp, species, site, plot)
```

-output

```
  species site plot  n
1    Acmi  kbs   D6  8
2    Amla umbs   B4  9
3    Amla umbs   C3 38
4    Amla umbs   D3 38
5    Ansp umbs   A4  8
```